# Why do I keep getting a 6 instead of 21?

Tags: javascript, arrays, average

The task is to get javascript to print the rounded average of the ages of the people in the array. I can‘t see why it's printing 6.

I've tried everything I can think of and this is the end result

```
function getRoundedAverageAge(people) {
  var sum = 0;
  for(var a = 0; a < people.length; a++){
    sum = people[a].age + sum;
    return Math.round(sum / people.length);
  }
}



/* Do not modify code below this line */

const examplePeopleArray = [
  { name: 'John', age: 19 },
  { name: 'Jack', age: 21 },
  { name: 'Jane', age: 22 }
    ];

console.log(getRoundedAverageAge(examplePeopleArray), '<-- should be 
21');
```

And then it prints "6". Help!

Comment: You need to remove your `return` outside of the loop. As it is, it is dividing 19 by 3.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It can help a lot if you quickly learn how to debug program code.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to phrase it, is that you can only `return` from a function once.

```js
function getRoundedAverageAge(people) {
  var sum = 0;
  for(var a = 0; a < people.length; a++){
    sum = people[a].age + sum;
  }
  return Math.round(sum / people.length);
}



/* Do not modify code below this line */

const examplePeopleArray = [
  { name: 'John', age: 19 },
  { name: 'Jack', age: 21 },
  { name: 'Jane', age: 22 }
    ];

console.log(getRoundedAverageAge(examplePeopleArray), '<-- should be 21');
```